# how to find out case when in select mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

this is my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=19b6e1298eba9eaa92ba2c726916d5d2

assume i have this table

```
CREATE TABLE Prime_Table (
  user_Id varchar(100),
 join_date date,
 platform varchar(100),
 country varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO Prime_Table VALUES
('895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19', '2020-01-01','IOS', 'United States'),
('2B4C47D7-0DDC-4007-B1CF-4E3C802E5D5D', '2020-01-02', 'IOS', 'United States'),
('5309F361-DBF9-4AF9-8B6B-79F377C3647C', '2020-01-02', 'IOS', 'United States'),
('79077D38-F49D-44E0-B47B-030954F6FE33', '2020-01-02', 'IOS', 'United States'),
('569D79E4-8EA8-4D0D-83F3-6EC3F4B307D9', '2020-01-03', 'IOS', 'Indonesia'),
('CF29B015-7337-429E-A055-EE9640033E69', '2020-01-03', 'IOS', 'United Kingdom'),
('4759E38F-7DEE-4D0E-91ED-9B8CB7C545FA', '2020-01-03', 'IOS', 'Lebanon'),
('499B35D0-84D9-43CE-B684-43A50F107866', '2020-01-04', 'IOS', 'Canada'),
('5C1ED286-BA84-434B-8FC7-97AF5235D051', '2020-01-04', 'IOS', 'Indonesia');


+--------------------------------------+------------+----------+----------------+
|               user_Id                | join_date  | platform |    country     |
+--------------------------------------+------------+----------+----------------+
| 895A8F53-C61C-471A-B934-CC2795286E19 | 2020-01-01 | IOS      | United States  |
| 2B4C47D7-0DDC-4007-B1CF-4E3C802E5D5D | 2020-01-02 | IOS      | United States  |
| 5309F361-DBF9-4AF9-8B6B-79F377C3647C | 2020-01-02 | IOS      | United States  |
| 79077D38-F49D-44E0-B47B-030954F6FE33 | 2020-01-02 | IOS      | United States  |
| 569D79E4-8EA8-4D0D-83F3-6EC3F4B307D9 | 2020-01-03 | IOS      | Indonesia      |
| CF29B015-7337-429E-A055-EE9640033E69 | 2020-01-03 | IOS      | United Kingdom |
| 4759E38F-7DEE-4D0E-91ED-9B8CB7C545FA | 2020-01-03 | IOS      | Lebanon        |
| 499B35D0-84D9-43CE-B684-43A50F107866 | 2020-01-04 | IOS      | Canada         |
| 5C1ED286-BA84-434B-8FC7-97AF5235D051 | 2020-01-04 | IOS      | Indonesia      |
+--------------------------------------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

i want to mapping from each country of users belong, i can make mapping like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(country, 'Total') AS `country`, 
       COUNT(a.user_id) AS `Count_User`,
       round(COUNT(a.user_id) / any_value(totalcount) * 100, 1) AS `Count_User(%)`
FROM Prime_Table a

JOIN ( SELECT
        COUNT(user_id) totalcount 
       FROM Prime_Table
  ) totals

GROUP BY a.country WITH ROLLUP;

and this is the output
+----------------+------------+---------------+
|    country     | Count_User | Count_User(%) |
+----------------+------------+---------------+
| Canada         |          1 |          11.1 |
| Indonesia      |          2 |          22.2 |
| Lebanon        |          1 |          11.1 |
| United Kingdom |          1 |          11.1 |
| United States  |          4 |          44.4 |
| Total          |          9 |         100.0 |
+----------------+------------+---------------+
```

but how to make all of those country into 2 categories, like US(United States) and non-US (United States) so the expected results become like this

```
+-------------------+-------------+----------------+
|      country      | count_users | count_users(%) |
+-------------------+-------------+----------------+
| United States     |           4 | 44.44%         |
| Non-United States |           5 | 55,56%         |
| Total             |           9 | 100            |
+-------------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Use `SUM(country = 'United States')` and `SUM(country != 'United States')` respectively instead of `COUNT(user_id)`, and `GROUP BY country = 'United States'`

Comment: @Akina make that an answer?

Comment: @ysth The answer needs to rewrite the query until correct one - too lazy. Do it if you want.

Comment: i've just follow your instruction but become like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=02bdc3b3e14321f6282c1ba62a3b485f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest change to make is just replace your FROM table with a subquery that changes non US countries:

```
SELECT COALESCE(country, 'Total') AS `country`, 
       COUNT(a.user_id) AS `Count_User`,
       round(COUNT(a.user_id) / any_value(totalcount) * 100, 1) AS `Count_User(%)`
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, CASE WHEN country != 'United States' THEN 'Non-United States' ELSE country END AS country
    FROM Prime_Table a
) a

JOIN ( SELECT
        COUNT(user_id) totalcount 
       FROM Prime_Table
  ) totals

GROUP BY a.country WITH ROLLUP;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5492fdcf37a63e65773aa8a6d146144d

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient way, but a way.
Extending your current queries.
Dump the first result in a temp table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stats
SELECT COALESCE(country, 'Total') AS `country`, 
       COUNT(a.user_id) AS `Count_User`,
       round(COUNT(a.user_id) / any_value(totalcount) * 100, 1) AS `Count_User(%)`
FROM Prime_Table a

JOIN ( SELECT
        COUNT(user_id) totalcount 
       FROM Prime_Table
  ) totals

GROUP BY a.country WITH ROLLUP;
```

And then `group by case` on this table:

```
select 
    (case 
     when country like '%United States%' then 'United States' 
     when country like '%Total%' then 'Total' 
     else 'Non-United States' end) as country, 
     sum(Count_User), 
     sum(`Count_User(%)`
from stats 
group by 
    (case 
     when country like '%United States%' then 'United States' 
     when country like '%Total%' then 'Total' 
     else 'Non-United States' end
     ) order by 3,1 desc;
```

Comment: thankyou very much, pls take a look my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=963ce857006cc50aea5ee62305a3ee00, can you make it the totals in bottom not in middle?

Comment: @FachryDzaky edited the answer. Just add an order by clause after the group by

Comment: Any clarification as to why `order by 3`? and how does it work?

Comment: @tcadidot0 order by 3 represents the 3rd column in the select query which is user %, and we know the user % of total will always be the maximum.

Comment: @hsnsd but if there are only US or only non-US countries, then the non-totals will have the same % and the order will not necessarily have the total last

Comment: That good knowledge @hsnsd, I never knew about that before, thanks. I do agree with ysth comment though, probably there is another way where the ordering will be certain?

Comment: @ysth oh yes. order by 3,1 desc would work then. But Non-US would come before US in that case, however Total will always be last